# passing hashes to subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine, hash

hi i am new to perl programming..and I am not able to get this code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Function definition
sub PrintHash{
   my (%hash) = @_;

   foreach my $key ( keys %hash ){
      my $value = $hash{$key};
      print "$key : $value\n";
   }
}
%hash = ('name' => 'Tom', 'age' => 19);

# Function call with hash parameter
PrintHash(%hash);
```

output of this code would be

> name : Tom
>     age : 19

I understood that how the keys being parsed,but i am not able to get the idea behind how the values are getting parsed.As i try to understand the flow of the program this line is responsible for parsing the values.

```
my $value = $hash{$key};
```

Can anyone explain in brief what is happening? please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PrintHash(%hash);
```

A hash in list context is a list of the key-value pairs contained in the hash. You can write the same line as:

```
PrintHash(qw(name Tom age 19));
```

or

```
PrintHash('age', '19', 'name', 'Tom');
```

The order doesn't matter, but pairs are preserved.
Then you assign that list to a new hash at the first line of the sub

```
my %hash = @_;
```

You can initialize a hash from a list ( key, value, key, value, ... )

The rest of the subroutine iterates over the hash and prints the key-value pairs.

```
foreach my $key ( keys %hash ){
    my $value = $hash{$key};
    print "$key : $value\n";
}
```

**keys %hash** returns the list of keys in %hash ( there is also **values %hash** ), then to access the value stored in a hash you use **$hash{$key}**